# postgres sql Query a field with Json data

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

We have a field in a table that contains JSON object.  There are array objects inside the json structure and we would have to extract values specifically from the array.  Below is a sample data in the json field

```
 children:[{server:,children:[{server:,newPage:,menuType:3,label:File Tax Forms,url:\/dashboard\/fileTaxForm},{server:,newPage:,menuType:3,label:View Filed Forms,url:dashboard\/viewFiledForms}],
```

Can you please throw some light on how to extract the values via sql query in the above json object.
Any help on this is much appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure it's a column defined as `jsonb` or at least `json`? The content would look different in that case (mainly: all strings must be quoted with `"`)

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract? Please **[edit]** your question and add the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the json to your question, it seems to have lost quotes.

If the JSON is inserted as follows

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{"children":[{"server":"","children":[{"server":"","newPage":"","menuType":3,"label":"File Tax Forms","url":"dashboard/fileTaxForm"},{"server":"","newPage":"","menuType":3,"label":"View Filed Forms","url":"dashboard/viewFiledForms"}]}]}');
```

into a table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test (somejson json);
```

then you could use a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT somejson::json->'children'->0->'children'->0->'label' as label, somejson::json->'children'->0->'children'->0->'url' as url  FROM test;
```

to get a result:

```
      label       |           url           
------------------+-------------------------
 "File Tax Forms" | "dashboard/fileTaxForm"
```